# MySQL query to set one value to 1 and all others to 0

Tags: mysql

This query is intended to update the inUse variable if the result of a form input, e.g. $_POST['eventID'] matches the eventID in the database, thus changing the inUse value for that event to 1, and all others to zero.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE events SET inUse=IF('$_POST['eventID']' = eventID, 1, 0)");
```

The database requires an integer, however I am concerned as I've dumped the value for $_POST['eventID'] which is showing up as a string. I've  tried using intval and int to no avail.

Or is the a problem in my query syntax?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your `IF()` dosn't have a `)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE events SET
inUse = ('$_POST['eventID']' = eventID);
```

This assumes that `inUse` is a boolean (which in mysql is implemented as a `TINYINT` with values either `1` or `0`, but whatever the case, mysql converts between boolean/int values just fine)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing from the query type that is PHP.

Regardless of a problem in your syntax (which is a missing bracket isn't it?), really don't use that post there. Have you tried sending a value of "'); DROP TABLE events" to your post variable yet? If not, I am sure someone else will!

If that value is an int, try

```
$num = (int)$_POST['eventID'];
mysql_query("UPDATE events SET inUse=($num = eventID), 1, 0");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped. I was using (int) in the wrong place and hence it wasn't working, also cheers for the syntax correction! Thanks again.

Comment: Just having the post in the query makes me shudder. I run a little shop and am up to about 5 people a day running through my post and get variables trying sql injection attacks with automated tools